# Getting Unauthorized while connecting to Azure Cognitive Search using Managed Identity

Tags: ruby, azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to access Azure Cognitive Search (ACS) using Managed Identity in Ruby On Rails application.

Following is the script been used

```rb
COGNITIVE_SEARCH_BASE_URL = "https://#{VaultService.get_secret('COGNITIVE-SEARCH-SERVICE-NAME')}.search.windows.net".freeze
API_VERSION = '2020-06-30'.freeze
endpoint = "#{COGNITIVE_SEARCH_BASE_URL}/indexes/temp/docs/$count?api-version=#{API_VERSION}"
api_url = URI(endpoint)
https = Net::HTTP.new(api_url.host, api_url.port)
https.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(api_url)
request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
request["Authorization"] =  AzureAd::ManagedIdentityTokenProvider.new('https://search.azure.com', client_id: ENV['AKS_MANAGED_IDENTITY_ID']).get_authentication_header
request = https.request(request)
JSON.parse(request.read_body)
```

Bearer token is generated by adapting the following reference:- https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/blob/master/runtime/ms_rest_azure/lib/ms_rest_azure/credentials/msi_token_provider.rb

Managed Identity has following access over roles for ACS:-

- Owner
- Search Service Contributor
- Search Index Data Contributor

Following is the configuration done for using RBAC access
[image]

Followed this documentation:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-security-rbac?tabs=config-svc-rest%2Croles-portal%2Ctest-rest%2Ccustom-role-portal%2Cdisable-keys-rest#test-role-assignments

**When I run the above script, I get 401 unauthorized error.**
Could anyone please help what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It's working now. I think it took sometime around 10 mins for the roles to assigned to Managed Identity. Earlier, I was assuming it would have taken a minute or so.

Comment: there is a disclaimer when you make this change in Azure that it can take up to 1/2 hour (I'm guessing it's to replicate the change across their structure).  We're so used to things being almost instant that it seems so weird to wait.